# why is sortBy so oddly unconstrained, and why no general sortOn

Tags: sorting, haskell

Example 2 at http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/sortBy_f.html defines the  comparison function `xxx a b = if (odd a) then LT else GT`.  Haskell seems happy with this as a comparison function, but I do not understand the meaning of "comparison" in such a case.  What is an application of allowing such things? (Here, 2>4 and 4>2.)

As a point of reference, consider the Python and Mathematica approaches: a list is sorted based on a univariate "key" function that maps list items to something already ordered.  This seems eminently sensible.  (In fact, Python dropped Haskell-like comparisons for sorting as superfluous and replaced them with sort keys.)  What is the basis for Haskell's (apparently) conflicting judgment on this?  Is there any talk of providing `sortOn` functionality to encourage a more coherent (?) notion of "comparison".  (I recognized that a "key" function could be used in a comparison function or in making the data type to be sorted an instance of `Ord`, but this just feels needlessly awkward and indirect for something so simple.)

What am I missing?  Is this just a legacy, like the one Python discarded, or is there a mathematical motivation for this situation?

Edit: As noted by Nouri, `Data.List.sortOn` does exist for lists.  This was apparently added in 2014.

Comment: [`sortOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) already exists; if the sorting algorithm is _stable_ then the comparison function does _not_ have to specify a [_strict weak ordering_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)

Comment: Why is an `Ord` instance awkward? Most of the time it can be automatically generated with a `deriving` clause on your data type definition and the main exceptions to that are when you want a special ordering to be the default (so you'd have to define the ordering regardless).

Comment: @DavidYoung Because you may want to sort the same data type in varying ways.

Comment: That's exactly the reason `sortBy` exists! An `Ord` instance lets you provide a default ordering, if you want to (like the typical ordering of integers) and, regardless of whether an `Ord` instance exists, `sortBy` allows you to sort in any way you'd like.

Comment: @behzad.nouri  
1. It only exists in Data.List, right?  I wanted a more general version (or at least one for Data.Sequence).
2. I'm not understanding your second point.  I'm suggesting that mapping to an Ord instance would be more sensible.

Comment: @DavidYoung Of course, but that observation does not address my question.

Comment: @Alan, `sortBy` [is also available](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#g:10) In `Data.Sequence`. Note also that you can use the `reflection` package to implement `sortBy` in terms of `sort` cleanly.

Comment: What do you mean by "key?" Unless I'm misreading the question, this seems like an important part, but I'm not sure what you mean. I would expect it to mean something like a key in a hash map, but a Haskell list doesn't work that way (because it is a linked list). I'm also not sure what a key would be in the context of `Data.Sequence`.

Comment: Rereading it, if you mean a key *function*, I'm not sure how that differs significantly from the `sortBy` approach. `sortOn` just uses an already existing `Ord` instance (which has its place as well), but if you just want to write a quick function to perform a certain kind of comparison in a sort then `sortBy` would be easier (say you want to sort favoring the second element of a pair rather than the first).

Comment: In fact, one nice use of monoids is using them with `sortBy`: You can sort by the second element then the first element of a list of pairs with `sortBy (comparing snd <> comparing fst)`. This provides a pretty readable and succinct little "language" for creating orderings and using them to sort things (which can be expanded to any number of criteria just by adding more "terms" with `<>`).

Comment: @DavidYoung One advantage of key functions is time efficiency. By mapping the potentially complex elements to, say, `Int`s and then doing comparisons only on `Int`s is faster then doing complex comparisons on the actual values. Obviously you are adding an O(n) space complexity.   Obiously this is different if you want to do simple comparisons like compare only the kth element of a tuple.

Comment: I object to your claim that Python is more sensible about what comparison functions it accepts. To use your phrasing: Python seems happy with `def __lt__(self, other): return other.isOdd()` as a comparison function, but I do not understand the meaning of "comparison" in such a case.

Comment: @DanielWagner You have misunderstood me.  My point was that Python abandoned comparison arguments to sort in favor of key functions, and they seem (to me) to have good reasons for this change.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, I know about `Data.Sequence.sortBy`.  Not finding a `Data.Sequence.sortOn` was the basis of my question.  Is it under consideration?  Thanks.

Comment: @Alan I believe I did understand you. But the "good reasons" you cite appear to be on the one hand that it is unfortunate to allow ill-behaved comparison functions like `xxx` and on the other hand that you have an aesthetic objection ("...this just _feels_ needlessly awkward and indirect...", emphasis mine). I can't speak to your aesthetics; but my point is that your technical objection doesn't seem to actually be a difference between the two languages or between new Python and old Python.

Comment: @DanielWagner  I believe the main reason for the Python change was time efficiency.  It is a real change: `List.sort` and `sorted` no longer accept a `cmp` argument.  Your point seems to be that we could still build objects with perverse magic comparison methods. That's true, but that is really not about the `key` and `cmp` arguments of sorting functions.  On the aesthetic/readability front, having used both `cmp` and `key` arguments in Python 2 sorting, I wound up *never* wanting `cmp` -- which is why I was so startled by seeing Haskell privilege `sortBy` over `sortOn`. Hope that's clearer.

Comment: @Alan, as the documentation for `sortOn` says, you can use `sortBy` with `comparing` (or ``compare `on` ...``) To cache the conversions, you can use `fmap` to pair the values with keys, then sort by the keys, or do it however you like. Haskell makes you be explicit about what you want to cache; Python seems to have decided it knows better. Also, good luck sorting `Rational`s or computable reals or search trees without a general ordering mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

`sortBy` is unconstrained in essentially the same ways, and for essentially the same reasons, that `Ord` instances generally are unconstrained. Haskell is not dependently typed. You simply can't state or prove, in Haskell, that a certain relation is actually a total ordering. In a language like Agda, `sortBy` could take a proof that the ordering really is one, and produce a proof that the result really is a sorted permutation of the input. This is not easy! The Python approach seems to lose some flexibility without gaining any guarantees, so it doesn't smell like a solution.

Comment: AFAIK the reason why Python moved to the key approach is efficiency.  If you are able to map complex objects into simple keys (like `int`s) then the O(nlog n) comparisons can be done pretty fast. Using a custom comparison function could potentially require O(n log n) costly comparisons. Using keys you need only O(n) potentially costing key function calls and you end up using O(n) extra space (but with generally a small constant there)

Comment: @Bakuriu, of course, there are any number of ways to layer that on top of Haskell's more flexible approach!

Answer (score 3):

Sorting by a function of the elements to some ordered type is easy to express in terms of `sortBy` and the standard `on` function (which I believe exists primarily for this precise use case):

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy)

-- | Sort in the Python/Mathematica way the question describes.
sortOn :: Ord key => (a -> key) -> [a] -> [a]
sortOn f = sortBy (compare `on` f)

-- Code example
type Person = String
type Age = Int    

example :: [(Person, Age)]
example = sortOn snd input
    where input = [ ("Mary", 33)
                  , ("Mario", 12)
                  , ("Mariama", 25)
                  , ("Mariano", 58)
                  ]
```

Some might object here that the key extraction function is not memoized—it will be called over and over on the same arguments (something like N log N calls, I wager.).  But that's easy to fix as well:

```
sortOn :: Ord key => (a -> key) -> [a] -> [a]
sortOn f = map fst 
         . sortBy (compare `on` snd) 
         . map (\a -> (a, f a))
```

And there's a third factor that should override the performance concerns several commenters have raised: if sorting really is the key performance bottleneck, then perhaps one shouldn't use Haskell's list type in the first place!  The [`vector-algorithms`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms) package provides several sorting algorithms on mutable `Vector`s.  They do use the `e -> e -> Ordering` interface discussed here, but again that should be easy to work around if it matters that much.

**TL;DR:** Meh.

Comment: The question was not about *how* to do the equivalent of `sortOn` but rather why `sortBy` was privileged.  (`sortOn` came late to the party for lists and doesn't even exist for Sequences.)  Nevertheless, I take your point.
(Well, there was another part to my question, but in retrospect it seems less interesting.)
Separately, doesn't `comparing` (in Data.Ord) accomplish what `on compare` does in your answer?
Cheers.

Comment: @Alan, if you send a message to libraries@haskell.org laying out a good argument for adding `Data.Sequence.sortOn`, and the list does not generally object, and your argument convinces me, then I will add it.

Comment: @Alan, `Data.Sequence` has now had both stable and unstable versions of `sortOn` for a few versions, Thanks to Donnacha Oisín Kidney. They're all based on heap sorts with different pairing heaps.

Answer (score 1):

> What is an application of allowing such things?

Depends upon the problem domain you are solving. When you do `sortBy xxx [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, it's just doing what it is supposed to do. `sortBy` is a function which accepts a function of type `(a -> a -> Ordering)`. So you can pass any function satisfying that type signature. Haskell doesn't and shouldn't restrict that!

> As a point of reference, consider the Python and Mathematica approaches: a list is sorted based on a univariate "key" function that maps list items to something already ordered.

Not a Python expert, but even with Python 3, I can get this to work:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x.sort(key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
>>> x
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

> Is this just a legacy, like the one Python discarded, or is there a mathematical motivation for this situation?

No, this is not a legacy. This is how it's supposed to work. :)

Comment: I don't really understand the idea that Haskell "shouldn't" restrict anything here.  That's why I'm asking for an application where one would want e.g. to violate asymmetry of the strict comparison.  `Data.List.sortOn` requires that the key function produce an instance or `Ord`, which totally makes sense to me.

Comment: @Alan the problem here is that being an instance of Ord doesn't guarantee you anything in particular. It's up to the programmer to guarantee that instances of Ord are well behaved.

Comment: @Alan and another problem is that you cannot create instances of Ord dynamically, e.g. by reading collation order from a file.

Comment: @n.m. Unless I'm misunderstanding you, this is readily addressed by a key function.  I'm looking for a reason (a true use case) for using a (potentially inefficient -- see Bakuriu's comments above) compare function rather than a key function.  (A key function cannot produce the inconsistent rankings illustrated in my original question, so presumably the use case will illustrate why such inconsistency can be desirable.)

Comment: @Alan "this is readily addressed by a key function" no, it is not. A key function cannot make an ill-behaved Ord instance well-behaved. "A key function cannot produce the inconsistent rankings" A key function does not produce any rankings by itself, it can only do so in conjunction with an instance of Ord. If that instance does not behave, the key function will jolly well produce inconsistent rankings. I'm not sure I can express myself any more clearly.

Comment: @n.m. So ... one could still screw things up by using a screwed up instance of `Ord` as the codomain of the `key` function. But why would you do that?  (Possible response: well why would one write a compare function like the one I posted.) In any case, I was addressing your subsequent comment. And, my motivating question remains: what is a use case where `sortOn` is not satisfactory but `sortBy` is?  
(In the background I make an assumption: `sortOn` is simpler, more intuitive, less error prone, and potentially more efficient.  Feel free to challenge this if you feel it is misleading.)

Comment: @Alan Well, like I said in the other comment, one possible use is that it is easy to make a new ordering by combining existing orderings with `sortBy`. To sort a hypothetical list of users by join date, last seen and finally alphabetically by user name you could write: `sortBy (comparing joinDate <> comparing lastSeen <> comparing username)`. It is possible to do this sort of thing with `sortOn`, but you'd need either new types for every ordering or to pack things into pairs in a way that reflects the particular order you want (which I suspect would be less efficient and maybe less intuitive).

Comment: @Alan "why would you do that" Who says I would? The original question was IIRC why Haskell won't police me doing that. The answer to that question is because it cannot. "what is a use case where sortOn is not satisfactory but sortBy is?" Alphabetical sorting of strings in human languages comes to mind. Transformed data would be larger than the original set, and allocations are not free. I didn't measure it though. Perhaps I should.

Comment: @n.m. That is certainly the best example offered yet, but I remain dubious.  Would you really reach for `sortBy` and supply it with nsome complicated comparison function?  I suspect you would make your strings an instance of `Ord` (as Haskell already does).

Comment: @Alan Each language has its own sorting rules, so no, can't do that. An instance of Ord per language is not feasible, the rules are normally stored in locale data files.

Comment: Sure, you might, especially if you wanted to compare some type that was an instance of `Ord` but you wanted to compare by some other metric.  The point is Haskell can only constrain by _type_ here, not by implementation.

Comment: @n.m.  Point taken.  I'm still dubious anyone would approach this problem that way.  I suspect they would wrap the ICU library.  But thanks.

Comment: @DavidYoung  OK, that's a good example.  I would be inclined to use `sortOn` with a key function that produces tuples, which I suspect would be more time efficient and less space efficient.  But thanks.

Comment: @n.m., that's what `reflection` is for! You can definitely have an `Ord` instance based on a config file if you like! But sorting strings based on `Ord` seems odd; I'd expect a bucket/trie sort to be better.

Answer (score 1):

pairwise comparison has some advantages, for example if you slightly change the  comparison function to sort odds before evens but in their natural order, for example

```
xxx a b | both odd || both even = compare a b
        | odd a && even b = LT
        | otherwise = GT
       where both f = f a && f b

> sortBy xxx [1..6]
[1,3,5,2,4,6]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be shorter to write `xxx a b = compare (even a, a) (even b, b)`?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Which means the key could just be (\x->(even x,x)), again raising the question, why is `sortBy` salient?

Answer (score 0):

`sortBy` isn't going to be terribly meaningful if the function you pass to it doesn't define some kind of [ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#Basic_definitions): either the result will depend on the implementation details of `sortBy`, or the result will not be "sorted" properly (since `sortBy` is allowed to take shortcuts assuming transitivity etc.)